# Can VSCode Extension package.json be edited during runtime?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In an extension, package.json is used to hold the commands and menus. However, it feels like it gets messy quickly. Can it be edited during runtime? I'm imagining that package.json is loaded at start-up or extension activation, and read out of memory, meaning it is not possible. If it is possible how would it be accomplished?

Comment: what do you want to modify in `package.json`?

Comment: It makes no sense to edit it after installation, so there is no API for that, but you can feel free to use node.js file API to locate and edit it. Keep in mind when you publish a new version, the whole folder of the old version will be lost.

Comment: I'd like to like to add commands and menus conditionally and more importantly with comments in my code since json doesn't support comments.

Comment: It can be edited during runtime and is quite easy to find.  You are right that the `package.json` is read on activation, so if you later make a change to it, the extension would have to be reactivated/vscode reloaded.   So in most cases this isn't a user-friendly way to go, unless you really need to do this.